# browser back button issue after logout laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel-5, browser-cache

i am working on laravel 5.0. i am facing following problem:

when user clicks on browser back button after logout, it shows the previous page.
i want them to redirect on homepage when they click back button if they have logged out already otherwise they can access the page.

i have tried this:

```
Route::get('logout','UserController@logout')->after('invalidate-browser-cache');
Route::filter('invalidate-browser-cache', function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'); 
    $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache'); 
    $response->headers->set('Expires','Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
});
```

i put this code in routes.php in app/http/

any otherway? another thing is that i am not able to find "filters.php" file. where is this located at?

Comment: This is not actually an issue but rather browser behavior. Dough user can use back button to navigate to protected page (which is cached) they can not perform any further action on the protected page once its refreshed. I suggest you use client side scripting like javascript

Comment: surprised with your anser. i have set option for no cache in my userLayout page. but it still caching the page. this is the issue with me. i dont want browser to cache my page.

Comment: any one with laravel 5.0?